# How to accept on a certain port with linux network code

Tags: linux, sockets, networking

I am in a situation where I must use a particular port for firewall reasons on one side to make a peer to peer connection. I was wondering if it's possible to open a connection with a client on a particular port. I know about the `listen()` and `accept()` functions.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use bind (http://linux.die.net/man/2/bind).

There are many examples of servers on the web.

Comment: So, I would bind this new socket that I've gotten to the port I want?

Comment: Yes you can bind to the port that you want